# Html table height="100%" not filling parent height

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables in my container. One of it will stick to the bottom of the container and the other will fill the remaining height of the parent

Style:

```
    .page
    {
        width: 21cm;
        min-height: 29.7cm;
        padding: 0.5cm;
        margin: 1cm auto;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        position: relative;
    }

<div class="page">
    <table class="table1" style="height: 100%;">
        <tr>Supposed to fill remaining space</tr>
    </table>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
        <table class="table2">
             <tr>Floats to the bottom</tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is for table1 to take up the remaining space left but it isnt filling up the space at all.

Comment: height:100%; requires a known height from parent' CSS, else it is 100% of none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drop the HTML table and use the display instead.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbXYoW)

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="tr fullH">
    <div class="td ">
      <section>
        <p> fill avalaible space left</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      <section>
        <p>Floats to the bottom and expand if needed</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.page
{
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 0.5cm;
  margin: 1cm auto;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /*position: relative; unneeded*/
  display:table;/* height turns to be min-height , table expands */
  table-layout:fixed;/* keeps width as set, height stills expands if needed */
}
.tr {
  display:table-row;
}
.td {
  display:table-cell;
}
.fullH {
  height:100%;
}
```

---

Using the `display:flex;` property makes it very simple:

[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyzKLM)

HTML

```
<div class="page">

      <section class="fullH">
        <p>Supposed to fill remaining space</p>
      </section>

      <section>
        <p>Floats to the bottom and expand if needed</p>
      </section>

</div>
```

and CSS

```
.page
{
  width: 21cm;
  height:29.7cm;
  padding: 0.5cm;
  margin: 1cm auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}

.fullH {
  flex:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it requires a height on the parent directly, your code looks like it will work on first look, but it doesn't for tables.
First you are adding content to **tr** directly add that to **td** to make the table adjust height of cell.

Here is a workaround code that will work fine:

```
.page
{
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 0.5cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
}
<div class="page">
    <div style="height:100%;">
    <table class="table1"  style="height:100%;">
        <tr><td>Supposed to fill remaining space</td></tr>
    </table>
   </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
        <table class="table2">
             <tr><td>Floats to the bottom</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is not the right way of creating layouts nor the right way to add styles. Inline styles are never a good practice